# I get error when I try to sent mail from portal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smtp

I use this  code to sentmailasync:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        //// Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        //return Task.FromResult(0);

        //Login password of sender
        var from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"];
        var pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["e_password"];

        //set address and port smtp-server from which main is sent 
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        //creating massage and destination address
        var mail = new MailMessage(from, message.Destination);
        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```

I published code in two productions in one machine it works fine.

In other machine I get this error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.100.172.242:587

Any idea why I get error above and how to fix it?

Comment: Are the two machines in the same network?

Comment: This looks to me as connectivity problem. Can you try to establish connection from the problematic computer with cmd command: `telnet smtp-mail.outlook.com 587` You can get telnet available from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Telnet Client.

Comment: @Obelixx, Talnet Client have to be tourned on?

Comment: @Michael Yes, in order to use it it should be enabled.